# Do supporting assemblies need to be registered in the GAC?

Tags: .net, windows, sharepoint, gac, global-assembly-cache

I recently had to register an assembly in my GAC for a custom sharepoint job I wrote.  Once installed it began throwing an error saying that it could not load an assembly "or one of its dependencies".  Do I need to register any of the supporting assemblies (System.Collections for instance) in the GAC in order to get my main assembly recognized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should register all referenced assemblies in the GAC which are not already present there.

Remark: `System.Collections` is a namespace and not an assembly which is part of the BCL and already present in the GAC.

Comment: So do I still need to register `System.Collections`?  I would think not but when I look in my GAC I see a ton of `System.Whatevers`.  I am assuming those are all namespaces too?

Comment: As I said `System.Collections` is **not** an assembly. It is a namespace which is contained in the `mscorlib` assembly which is already present in the GAC. Namespaces should be *used* like: `using System.Collections;` in the top of your source file.

Comment: Sorry, previous comment was posted while incomplete.  I understand that it is NOT and assembly.  My Point is that I see a bunch of namespaces (System.Data for instance) in my GAC which makes me wonder if System.Collections should be in there.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, `System.Data` **is an assembly**. `System.Collections` **is not**. You can deploy only assemblies into the GAC.

Comment: Hmm, why does MSDN say `System.Data Namespace` in this link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx  How do I tell the difference between a name space and an assembly if I can't just look it up on MSDN?

Comment: Personally I prefer Reflector than MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

All of the assemblies that comprise the .NET Framework should already be in the GAC. So the assembly that contains System.Collections should not need to be registered.

However, any custom built assemblies that your code depends on should be put in the GAC.